# Let $\overline {X}_{0}\in \mathbb{R} ^{n}$ and $R>0$. Prove

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $x_0\in\Bbb R^n$ and $R > 0$. Prove $\{x\in\Bbb R^n: \| x - x_0 \| \le R\}$ is complete.

Comment: I tried to preserve your intent in converting to $\LaTeX$, but what you wrote really doesn’t make sense. What is $\overline{X}_0$? Is $R$ the same as $r$? Should the first bit be ‘Let $x_0\in\Bbb R^n$’?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Compactness implies completeness in metric spaces.

Comment: I don’t know why this was down-voted: it’s a perfectly good hint.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I wrote "connectedness" instead of "completeness"; I edited my answer but the -1 stayed.

Comment: Ah, that explains it; oh, well. I’ll leave my comment, since the -1 is still there.